# How to change the format of the datetime along with changing from 12 hour to 24 hour?

Tags: php, datetime, format

If I have this date: `"16/2/2014 3:41:01 PM"` and would like to change it to the format: `"2014-02-16 15:41:01"`. 
How can I do it with PHP? 
I tried this:

```
$date = "16/2/2014 3:41:01 PM"
$newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date));
```

but it keeps returning `"1970-01-01 00:00:00"`.

Comment: Set your default time zone for accurate results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current format of your `$date` string is invalid in terms of how PHP reads and parses dates - See these two URLs for specifics:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Essentially, when using slashes (`/`) as date separators, PHP assumes you're entering `MM/DD/YYYY`. If at all possible, I'd see about updating whatever input created that date string to save it in `MM/DD/YYYY` format - That would probably be the best solution.

However, if that's not an option, based on what you've given, one method would be to swap the `16` and `2` to go from a DMY to an MDY format. Here's an example on how to do that using `explode()` and string concatenation:

```
<?php

// The original string you provided, with a date in `DD/MM/YYYY` format
$dateString = "16/2/2014 3:41:01 PM";

// The explode function will let us break the string into 3 parts, separated by the forward slashes. Using your example, these gives us an array containing the following:
// 0 => '16'
// 1 => '2'
// 2 => '2014 3:41:01 PM'
$stringPieces = explode('/', $dateString, 3);

// Piece the above array back together, switching the places of entries 0 and 1 to create a date in the format `MM/DD/YYYY`. This results in:
// 2/16/2014 3:41:01 PM"
$newDateString = $stringPieces[1] . '/' . $stringPieces[0] . '/' . $stringPieces[2];

// Use the reformatted date string in the date() function:
$newDate =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($newDateString));

var_dump($newDate);
```

The output of `var_dump()` in my testing was `string(19) "2014-02-16 15:41:01"`

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

**Use this function**

### Date and Time format

1: This function will help you

```
function date_his($date = '')
{
    if ($date == '') {
        return $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    } else {
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date));
    }
    return $date;
}
```

2: While store in to database call this function like this

`$date = date_his();`

it will consider `current date` and `current time`

3: If you want to store the `date` from date field call like this

`$date = date_his($_POST['field_name']);`

### Bonus

It converts any date and time format into `YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss`

Comment: I'm not seeing how this addresses the original question?